# Does someone know how to simplify endless if elif else statements in this algorithm?

Tags: python, if-statement, range, conditional-statements

I am trying to write a grade converter that changes number grades like 88% to a letter grade (i.e. B+) but I feel that there is a simpler way than using endless elif statements. Ideally I would like to have one condition that determines the letter based on the range and another condition that determines whether to assign a + or - based on a separate range. Here is the current code:

```
def convert_score_to_grade_w_plus_and_minus(score):
if score in range(98, 101):
    return 'A+'
elif score in range(93, 98):
     return 'A'
elif score in range(90, 93):
    return 'A-'
elif score in range(88, 90):
    return 'B+'
elif score in range(83, 88):
    return 'B'
elif score in range(80, 83):
    return 'B-'
elif score in range(78, 80):
    return 'C+'
elif score in range(73, 78):
    return 'C'
elif score in range(70, 73):
    return 'C-'
elif score in range(68, 70):
    return 'D+'
elif score in range(63, 68):
    return 'D'
elif score in range(60, 63):
    return 'D-'
elif score in range(60):
    return 'F'
else: 
    return 'INVALID SCORE'
```

Comment: You could use a list of (range, letter) tuples instead.

Answer (score 5):

You can store your scores in a list of tuples, then return the result for which the score matches using list comprehension.

```
scores = [('A+', 99, 101), ('A', 93, 98), ('A-', 90, 93)]

score = 91

[result[0] for result in scores if score in range(result[1], result[2])][0]
#'A-'

# without range

[result[0] for result in scores if score > result[1] and score < result[2]][0]
```

You can expand the scores list to include as many score brackets as you want.

Cleaned the above up a bit;

```
def get_grade(score):
    scores = [('A+', 99, 101), ('A', 93, 98), ('A-', 90, 93)]
    result = [grade for grade, low, high in scores if score > low and score < high]
    return result[0] if result else 'Invalid Score'
```

Comment: @LukeSkipSchilperoort Bear in mind that you don't need to use `range()` for this, I certainly wouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways you can do this, and LPython's answer is a great approach for the general case of how to convert a bunch of if statements into a data structure.

But note that you can also refactor the original implementation! In your specific case where the ranges you're considering are well-ordered and exclusive, you can alternatively think of grades as representing not ranges but cutoffs. For example:

```py
def convert_score_to_grade_w_plus_and_minus(score):
  if score >= 98:
      return 'A+'
  elif score >= 93:
       return 'A'
  elif score >= 90:
      return 'A-'
  elif score >= 88:
      return 'B+'
  elif score >= 83:
      return 'B'
  elif score >= 80:
      return 'B-'
  elif score >= 78:
      return 'C+'
  elif score >= 73:
      return 'C'
  elif score >= 70:
      return 'C-'
  elif score >= 68:
      return 'D+'
  elif score >= 63:
      return 'D'
  elif score >= 60:
      return 'D-'
  elif score >= 0:
      return 'F'
  else: 
      return 'INVALID SCORE'
```

Could then be simplified to:

```py
def convert_score_to_grade_w_plus_and_minus(score):
  grade_cutoffs = (('A+', 98), ('A', 93), ..., ('D', 63), ('D-', 60), ('F', 0))
  for grade, cutoff in grade_cutoffs:
    if score >= cutoff:
      return grade

  return 'INVALID SCORE'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 def convert_score(score):
  if score<=60:
    return 'F'
  first_digit = int(score/10)
  if score%10>=8:
    backgrade = '+'
  elif score%10>=3 and score%10<8:
    backgrade = ''
  else:
    backgrade = '-'
  frontgrade = chr(74-(first_digit))

  return frontgrade + backgrade
```

similar to Hamms but instead of cutoffs, looking at it as the first and last digits affecting the first and last characters of the grades respectively.

Answer (score 0):

One "issue" with some of the other answers is that it will loop through a `range` object resulting in more calculations then necessary. You can leverage tuple unpacking and iterate through a list. There's also the handy feature where you can do things like `0 < x < 1` to do the comparisons in one shot.

```
def convert_score_to_grade_w_plus_and_minus(score):
    grade_ranges = [
        (98, 101, 'A+'), (93, 98, 'A'), (90, 93, 'A-'),
        (88, 90, 'B+'), (83, 88, 'B'), (80, 83, 'B-'),
        (78, 80, 'C+'), (73, 78, 'C'), (70, 73, 'C-'),
        (68, 70, 'D+'), (63, 68, 'D'), (60, 63, 'D-'),
        (0, 60, 'F'),
    ]

    for lower, upper, grade in grade_ranges:
        if lower <= score <= upper:
            return grade

    return "Invalid Score"

for score in [70, 34, 99, 102]:
    print(score, convert_score_to_grade_w_plus_and_minus(score))
# (70, 'C-')
# (34, 'F')
# (99, 'A+')
# (102, 'Invalid Score')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
def convert_score_to_grade_w_plus_and_minus(score):
    if score > 100:
        return 'INVALID SCORE'
    score = 99 if score > 99 else score
    letter = chr(9 - math.floor(score / 10) + 65) if score >= 60 else 'F'
    return letter + ('+' if score % 10 >= 8 and not letter == 'F' else ('' if score % 10 >= 3 or letter == 'F' else '-'))
```

Explanation:

1. Clip score higher than `99` at `99` (if valid).
2. Find a grade letter knowing that `A` is `65` in ASCII.
3. Add `+`, nothing or `-` depending on the remainder of the `score % 10`. If it's `F` do not add anything.